# How to return All Parents which contain at least all pre-defined children

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

An example class (many-to-many relation) :

```
public class Parent
{
     Guid Id;
     IList<Child> Children;
}

public class Child
{
     Guid Id;
     IList<Parent> Parents;
}
```

Let's consider that all the mappings are implemented and working correctly.

We have a method in a repository:

```
public class MyRepository
{
     public IList<Parent> GetParents(IList<Child> children)
     {
          return Session.QueryOver ... ?
     }
}
```

Using the QueryOver API, I want to return all Parents that have ALL children. Parents can have more than the defined children, but the defined ones must exist.

How would the query be?

Comment: Have you looked if my answer (or a variation on its theme) works for you? Some feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The NHibernate `QueryOver` and `Criteria` way of doing things is not that intuitive (to me at least). In LINQ you could do it using this query:

```
return Db.Parents.Where(x => 
    x.Children.Count(c => children.Contains(c)) == children.Length);
```

or (closer to the NHibernate solution below)

```
return from child in Db.Children.Where(c => children.Contains(c))
       from parent in child.Parents
       group parent by parent.Id into g
       where g.Count() == children.Length
       select g.Single();
```

While there may be simpler ways, I believe something like this should work:

```
var childIds = children.Select(c => c.Id).ToArray();
Parent parent = null;
Child child = null;

return Session
    .QueryOver.Of<Child>(() => child)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Id).IsIn(childIds)
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Parents, () => parent)
    .Where(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Count(() => parent.Id), childIds.Length))
    .Select(Projections.Group(() => parent.Id));
```